# Doubt related to Convergent of sequence and its subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers, if $\{x_{nk}\} $ are convergent for $\forall K \geq 2$ then Is $\{x_n\} $ convergent??

My intuition is yes, because for different $k$, the subsequences  $\{x_{2n}\},\{x_{3n}\}, \{x_{4n}\}, \dots $ are convergent so they must convergent to same limit, then can we say $\{x_{k}\}$ is also convergent ??

Any hints and solutions are well appreciated.

Comment: Try to take $x_n=1$ if $n$ is a prime number, otherwise $x_n=0$.

Comment: @Mark Yeah that works well. Thanks!